# Получение любого контента запроса

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Есть некий `rest`-сервис, который ожидает некий формат `json`:

```
 [HttpPost("getdoc")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ReceivingDocumentAsync([FromBody] DocumentRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
```

Но если нам отправят невалидный `json` или другую структуру `json`, то параметр `request` будет равен `null`.

Мне надо логировать любой `json`, который мне приходит, чтоб понимать, что другая система нам шлет. То есть нужно, чтобы был тип не `DocumentRequest`, а какой нибудь универсальный, чтобы код выглядел как то так:

```
[HttpPost("getdoc")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ReceivingDocumentAsync([FromBody] string request, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        myLogger.Write(request);
        var desRequest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DocumentRequest>(request);
        ....
```

Подскажите, как это сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Что только не попробовал и string и stream и HttpRequestMessage  и прочее.

А оказалось все проще: object

Comment: Окей, но это не хорошее решение. А чтобы узнать хорошее, надо видеть сам JSON. Невалидный JSON - это тот JSON, который содержит синтаксическую ошибку, то есть не может быть десереализован в принципе. Решение, которое вы предлагаете будет работать только с валидным JSON.